# Applies the Autoplay Policy to Chrome Embedded Framework?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome, chromium-embedded

I'm searching for the answer for a long time so I decided to ask it here:

Does the [Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) only apply to the chrome app or does it also apply to the chrome embedded framework?